# How is the state for COM objects stored?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

Consider this example from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/example--the-open-dialog-box) of using a File Open Dialog through COM:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <shobjidl.h> 

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | 
        COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IFileOpenDialog *pFileOpen;

        // Create the FileOpenDialog object.
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, 
                IID_IFileOpenDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileOpen));

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Show the Open dialog box.
            hr = pFileOpen->Show(NULL);

            // Get the file name from the dialog box.
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IShellItem *pItem;
                hr = pFileOpen->GetResult(&pItem);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    PWSTR pszFilePath;
                    hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath);

                    // Display the file name to the user.
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        MessageBoxW(NULL, pszFilePath, L"File Path", MB_OK);
                        CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
                    }
                    pItem->Release();
                }
            }
            pFileOpen->Release();
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I was wondering was how interface methods (`Show` and `GetResult` in this case) are able to modify and access object state when no pointer or handle is passed to identify the instance they are operating on.

Having looked on MSDN there does not seem to be anything that explains how this works. I hope someone could provide some insight into how this works

Comment: `pFileOpen` as `this`?

Comment: when no pointer or handle is passed to identify the instance they are operating on - any com interface method got this pointer in the first argument. this is pointer to interface

Comment: Read this: [The Component Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model). What you are seeing in the sample is what C++ is known for: Invisible code. The class member access in C++ isn't actually accessing class members.

Comment: I was under the impression however that the very same code would compile in C, where there is no concept of "this" and classes.

Comment: The same code does not compile in C. For C, you need to do (for example) `pFileOpen->lpVtbl->Show(pFileOpen, NULL);`

Comment: Of course the very same code does not compile using a C compiler. Clearly, `reinterpret_cast<void**>` isn't valid C. Even if you dropped it, it still would look different (as Raymond pointed out). You can instruct the preprocessor to include convenience macros (so that you won't have to spell out the interface pointer multiple times) by defining `COBJMACROS` prior to including the header file. If you want the preprocessor to use the C interface declarations in C++ code, define the `CINTERFACE` preprocessor symbol prior to including the header file.

Comment: It's been a while, Have you solved your problem with the help of the community?

Answer (score 1):

The ABI of GetResult is really `HRESULT __stdcall GetResult(IFileDialog*pThis, IShellItem**resultItem)`.

C++ hides this from you when you use a compiler that is able to follow the COM ABI layout, it will pass the hidden this pointer as the first parameter for you.

If you wanted to do this in pure C it would actually look like this:

```
IShellItem*pItem;
IFileDialog*pDialog = ...;
...
pDialog->lpVtbl->GetResult(pDialog, &pItem);
```